# Generar un backup full en SQL Server mediante variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy buscando generar backups full por medio de variables en SQL Server

El script que estoy utilizando es el siguiente

```
declare @fecha varchar(50)
declare @query varchar(500)
declare @dbname varchar(500);
declare @SERVERNAME varchar (50)
SET @dbname='PruebaBackup'
SET @SERVERNAME=(SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'SERVER NAME')
SET @fecha=(select convert(varchar, getdate(), 23))

SET @query=('BACKUP DATABASE [PruebaBackup] TO  DISK = N''R:\SQL_Backup\Temporal\@SERVERNAME'+@dbname+@fecha+'.bak'''+
'WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N''@dbname-Full Database Backup''
, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10')

exec(@query)
```

Pero al obtener el backup no se imprime el nombre del host, me pueden asesorar sobre como se debe utilizar la variable para imprimirlo en el nombre, por favor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que tienes el nombre de la variable `@SERVERNAME` dentro de un string, dónde no se evalúa.

Lo que tienes que hacer es sacarla del string, tal como ya tienes las variables `@dbname` y `@fecha`:

```
SET @query=('BACKUP DATABASE [PruebaBackup] TO  DISK = N''R:\SQL_Backup\Temporal\' 
    + @SERVERNAME
    + @dbname
    + @fecha
    + '.bak'''
    + ' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'''
    + @dbname
    + '-Full Database Backup''
, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10')
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, ya obtengo el backup según lo esperado